# JMeter, same parameter used multiple times in single request. How to use multiple values from CSV file

Tags: csv, parameters, jmeter

For each post request I send via JMeter, part of the body uses a parameter like below

```
   {
      "product": "Coke",
      "quantity": 100,
      "purchaseOrderId": "${purchaseid}"
    },
    {
      "product": "Tango",
      "quantity": 100,
      "purchaseOrderId": "${purchaseid}"
    },
    {
      "product": "pepsi",
      "quantity": 100,
      "purchaseOrderId": "${purchaseid}"
    },
```

I also have a CSV file for parameter "${purchaseid}".  Lets say the CSV contains the following names

purchaseid

```
Paul
James
Sarah
Jane
```

Currently, when I run the jmeter test the first request will do this.

```
   {
      "product": "Coke",
      "quantity": 100,
      "purchaseOrderId": "Paul"
    },
    {
      "product": "Tango",
      "quantity": 100,
      "purchaseOrderId": "Paul"
    },
    {
      "product": "pepsi",
      "quantity": 100,
      "purchaseOrderId": "Paul"
    },
```

The question is how do I make JMeter do the following instead from the same CSV file with the above example:

```
   {
      "product": "Coke",
      "quantity": 100,
      "purchaseOrderId": "Paul"
    },
    {
      "product": "Tango",
      "quantity": 100,
      "purchaseOrderId": "James"
    },
    {
      "product": "pepsi",
      "quantity": 100,
      "purchaseOrderId": "Sarah"
    },
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Using the CSV with same parameter(purchaseid) is resulting the expected result. You need to have the JSON  (and csv accordingly) configured uniquely to fetch different data every time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will  be able to use CSV Data Set Config for this purpose as it doesn't take the next value on each use, it does update the variable value on each iteration or virtual user (depending on [sharing mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66094919/jmeter-groovy-webdriver-sampler-dynamic-name-with-response-code-500/66098361#66098361) setting)

Your scenario can be implemented using either [__CSVRead()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) or [__StringFromFile()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile) functions.