# JMeter Groovy - WebDriver Sampler Dynamic Name with Response Code 500

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have tired to below code and variable with JMeter Groovy WebDriver Sampler. It's not working and return the Response Code 500 "ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable". But I hard code the variable name and working find. The problem of XML variable is Dynamic and the numbers will be changed for every time loading from the Chrome. Can you please advise?

Variable not working:
WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//ul[contains(@id,'dropdown-menu-')]/li")).click();

Variable working fine:
WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//ul[@id='dropdown-menu-2724']/li")).click();

I also tried with below codes but didn't work.

WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//ul[contains(@id,'dropdown-menu-')]/li")).sendKeys("dropdown-menu-");
WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//ul[starts-with(@id,'dropdown-menu-')]/li")).sendKeys("dropdown-menu-");

below codes also don't work:

WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.id("dropdown-menu-").sendKeys("dropdown-menu-"));
WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.id("dropdown-menu-").sendKeys(Keys.ENTER));

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlsKM.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jTvb.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6v4nY.png)

Answer (score 0):

My expectation is that when you use [contains() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains) it tries to click the **first** element which is found and most probably the one you're trying to click is not the first one matching your XPath query.

We cannot suggest a better way of finding the element without seeing full response, however I would suggest sticking to this `Confirm` text and then calculating the [preceding-sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/preceding-sibling), see [XPath Axes](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp) article.

Your selector must be:

1. Unique
2. Matching exactly the element you want to interact with
3. The element needs to be visible
4. The element needs to be clickable

Selectors can be tested using i.e. [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools)

You can also see [Mixing Selenium Into Your Load Scenario](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/mixing-selenium-into-your-load-scenario) article

Comment: HI DT, Thanks for your replied. When I click on the user name and it will have a dropdown logout button. And clicking the Logout button, it will show the Confirm page to logging out the system. (Please refer the attached No. 3 screen capture). The problem is the JMeter Groovy script is not clicking on the "Logout" button with this syntax. Looks like the script not recognize this code "("//ul[@id='dropdown-menu-2724']/li")". Can you please advise more suggest? Thanks a lot.